# Ruby on Rails foreign key migration on MariaDB 10.0.20 Server does not apply

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, mariadb

I am trying to apply a database migration on my Ruby on rails project that defines a reference and foreign key constraint.

The migration itself works fine on a dev Sqlite3 DB and also on a MariaDB Server using the Aria storage engine. To support foreign key constraints we are using InnoDB (here: XtraDB) storage engine in the live MariaDB 10 server.

When applying the migration on live, it fails with the error message stated below.

```
== 20150831210234 AddStyleToPiece: migrating ==================================
-- add_reference(:nv_pieces, :style, {:index=>true, :foreign_key=>true})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table storage engine 'InnoDB' does not support the create option 'TRANSACTIONAL=1': ALTER TABLE `nv_pieces` ADD `style_id` int(11)/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:305:in `query'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:305:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:305:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:231:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:663:in `add_reference'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:631:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:631:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:651:in `method_missing'
/srv/httpd/rails-app/db/migrate/20150831210234_add_style_to_piece.rb:3:in `change'
```

I am aware that the MariaDB server does not support TRANSACTIONAL for the XtraDB storage engine.

This seems to be som consistency issue between the mysql2 gem, the libmariadbclient and the server but I couldn't find where the statement is generated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out myself.

After not finding any hint of TRANSACTIONAL=1 in the gem source, rails itself or even the MariaDB client library I experimented with the MariaDB.

The statement does NOT contain the TRANSACTIONAL parameter.

This seems to be a bug in MariaDB 10.0.21. If a table is created as MyISAM or ARIA engine or was at some point in the past converted to this engine type, a later conversion to INNODB and any subsequent ALTER TABLE statement produces the warning.

This can be reproduced using the following SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb;
CONNECT testdb;
CREATE TABLE testtable (id INT(11)) ENGINE=INNODB;
ALTER TABLE testtable ENGINE=INNODB;
ALTER TABLE testtable ENGINE=INNODB;
ALTER TABLE testtable ENGINE=ARIA TRANSACTIONAL=1;
ALTER TABLE testtable ENGINE=INNODB;
SHOW WARNINGS;
ALTER TABLE testtable ENGINE=INNODB;
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

Result:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> connect testdb;
Connection id:    6698
Current database: testdb

MariaDB [testdb]> create table testtable (id INT(11)) ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.30 sec)

MariaDB [testdb]> alter table testtable ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [testdb]> alter table testtable ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.36 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [testdb]> alter table testtable ENGINE=ARIA TRANSACTIONAL=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.49 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [testdb]> alter table testtable ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.54 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

MariaDB [testdb]> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                            |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1478 | Table storage engine 'InnoDB' does not support the create option 'TRANSACTIONAL=1' |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [testdb]> alter table testtable ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.39 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

MariaDB [testdb]> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                            |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1478 | Table storage engine 'InnoDB' does not support the create option 'TRANSACTIONAL=1' |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

> TRANSACTIONAL is only applicable for Aria tables.

Reference:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-table/#transactional

So leave it off when creating InnoDB/XtraDB tables.

FOREIGN KEYS are supported.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, unfortunately that is exactly my issue - I am aware that it is not applicable but I didn't create the statement, it is generated somewhere between my Rails App and the mariadbclient lib - I have no idea where it comes from...

Comment: Alas, another case of a 3rd party software getting in the way.